# ConcurrentHashMap foreach loop problem

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a concurrenthashmap called users. I have user objects in it with some integer keys that is not id. I want to find the user with a given id. Therefore, I check all elements of hashmap and return the user object if it is present. Here is my code :

```
    for(User u : users.values()) {
        logger.error("u.getId() : " + u.getId());
        logger.error("id : " + id );
        if( u.getId() == id ) {
            logger.error("match");
            return u;
        }
    }
    logger.error("Not found: id:" + id);
    for(User u : users.values()) {
        logger.error(u.getPos() + ". user: " + u.getId());
    }
```

However even tough my u.getId() and id are the same I cannot see "match" at my logs.

213 matches but It can not enter the following if statement. 
here are my logs:

[image]

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What type returned from User.getId() method and what type of id variable? If it is not a primitive type, you need to use equals() instead of ==.

By the way, a good static code analyzer like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can find such kind of errors.

Comment: you are right. they are Long. I should have used equals. and it explains comparing them true sometimes. I'll try now.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't shown the types involved, but is it possible that `id` or `getId()` is an `Integer` instead of an `int`? If so, you'll be comparing *references*, so you should just use

```
if (u.getId().equals(id))
```

to compare the values *within* the `Integer` objects. Be careful if `getId` can return null though...